# apparent size of an astronomical body

Tags: units

What's the name of the measure of apparent (visible) size of a body? e.g. the Sun and the Moon appear to be roughly the same size, despite the Sun being vastly bigger - because the Moon is much closer. What's this apparent size called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular size. That is, the vieving angle that the body spans on sky.

Answer (score 12):

It's **[angular diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter)** (a.k.a **angular size** or **apparent size**). This [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/) comic strip shows in an interesting way the angular size of some of the most remarkable objects in the sky:

[image: Comic about apparent size of celestial bodies]